# Why is the rectangular window called 'rectangular'?

Tags: terminology

In what way does it have a rectangular shape? Does it have something to do with a polar-coordinates graph?

Comment: In the discrete time domain, a rectangular window has weights $[\dots, 0, 0, 1, 1, \dots, 1, 1, 0, 0, \dots]$, which when plotted, looks like a rectangle.

Comment: @AndyWalls OK, thanks! One more question -- is it called a 'window' because it is metaphorically like looking through a framed glass window or is it a window (interval) of time?

Comment: Interval of time: a time window.